# Find $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin^4x + \cos^4x} dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, substitution

I was wondering, how to calculate the following definite integral that appeared in an integration bee (preferably the quickest way possible).

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin^4x + \cos^4x} dx$$

Comment: What have you done, as a baseline solution, prior to asking for the "quickest (subjective) way"?

Comment: The usual dictum is to use double-angle formulas for even powers (and $u$-substitution for odd powers) of sine and cosine.  You might well have a better approach available, but Readers need some benchmark against which they can decide if their suggestions improve upon your present understanding.

Comment: I will be providing more context / baselines in my future questions. I apologize for not doing so here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x = \frac{3+\cos(4x)}{4}$$
(see for example [How to simplify $\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x$ using trigonometrical identities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458305/how-to-simplify-sin4-x-cos4-x-using-trigonometrical-identities)).

Hence, by letting $z=e^{it}$, $dz=zidt$ and recalling that $\cos(t)=\frac{z+1/z}{2}$, we get
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin^4x + \cos^4x} dx&=
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d(4x)}{3+\cos(4x)} \\
&=\int_{0}^{8\pi}\frac{dt}{3+\cos (t)}=4\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{3+\cos (t)}\\
&=4 \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz/(zi)}{3+\frac{z+1/z}{2}}\\
&=\frac{8}{i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2 + 6z + 1}\\
&=16\pi\,\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2 + 6z + 1},2\sqrt{2}-3\right)\\
&=16\pi\,\left.\frac{1}{(z^2 + 6z + 1)'}\right|_{z=2\sqrt{2}-3}\\
&=16\pi\,\frac{1}{2(2\sqrt{2}-3) + 6}=2\sqrt{2}\pi.
\end{align*}

Comment: Any idea on how to proceed after this? The indefinite integral is particularly nasty and the bounds on the definite integral appear to be nice. What kind of manipulations can be performed to find the definite integral?

Comment: @JayJuly Any further doubt? P.S. Two downvotes. WOW!

Comment: @Robert Z I got the same result by another way! +1

Comment: I won't downvote, but consider, please: do you want to show how clever you are, or do you want to help the OP? If it's the latter, you should explain your steps more generously.

Comment: @ Professor Vector OP Asked for the "the quickest way possible". So give it a try. I am ready to give all the explanations that JayJuly is going to ask.

Comment: @Professor Vector Show us your solution, please.

Comment: @Robert Z I apoligize (should have read the original question more carefully): they didn't know what they were asking for, you're correct.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: no, thanks, I'm not a textbook. As I admitted already, I missed what the OP was asking for (brave, very brave), so the answer is absolutey ok.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It does appear that the complex substitution is quite useful in scenarios with constants mixed with cos or sin, like the 3 + cos(t). I am slightly confused on the part with Res. I am trying to research this operation online but it's difficult for me to understand this calculation. Would you mind explaining it, at least in terms of integral if not more generally? Thank you once again!

Comment: @JayJuly  By Residue Theorem, we have to compute the residue at the roots of $z^2 + 6z + 1$ which are inside $|z|=1$, that is at $z_0=2\sqrt{2}-3$. Since the order of this root is $1$, $z_0$ is a simple pole and  the residue is equal to $1$ over the derivative of  $z^2 + 6z + 1$ evaluated at $z_0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles

Comment: @RobertZ Hello, I have "checkmarked" your answer as I really like the creativity used, and I do this technique is applicable to other integrals with sin and cosine functions.

Comment: @JayJuly I am glad the my answer was useful.

Answer (score 5):

First, note the integrand  has period $\pi$ and has a symmetry w.r.t. the lines $x=\dfrac\pi2$ and $x=\dfrac\pi4$. As a consequence,
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin^4x + \cos^4x}\,\mathrm d\mkern 2mu x= 8\int_{0}^{\tfrac\pi4} \frac{1}{\sin^4x + \cos^4x}\,\mathrm d\mkern 2mux $$

*Bioche's rules* suggest to set $\;t=\tan x$, so that $\;\mathrm d\mkern 2mu x=\dfrac{\mathrm d\mkern 2mu  t}{1+t^2}$.

But actually, we even may set $\;u=\tan 2x$, $\;\mathrm d\mkern 2mu u=2(1+\tan^2x)\,\mathrm d\mkern 2mu x$. Indeed
\begin{align}
\sin^4x+\cos^4x&=(\sin^2x +\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-\frac12\sin^22x\\
&=1-\frac12\frac{\tan^2 2x}{1+\tan^2 2x}=\frac{2+\tan^2 2x}{2(1+\tan^2 2x)},
\end{align}
so that the integral is
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{2(1+u^2)}{2+u^2}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d\mkern 2mu u}{2(1+u^2)}= \int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm d\mkern 2mu u}{2+u^2}=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\,\arctan\biggl(\frac u{\sqrt 2}\biggr)\biggm\vert_0^\infty=\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}, $$
and finally
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin^4x + \cos^4x}\,\mathrm d\mkern 2mu x=2\sqrt2\,\pi.$$

Comment: Why you answer is different?

Comment: Don't know, and I'm too tired to check my computations now. What I know is I took into account the discontinuities for the change of variable on the given interval of integration .

Answer (score 3):

The substitution $\tan{x}=t$ helps.

$dt=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}dx=(1+t^2)dx$.

Thus, $dx=\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$.
$$\sin^4x+\cos^4x=2\cos^4x-2\cos^2x+1=\frac{2}{(1+t^2)^2}-\frac{1}{1+t^2}+1.$$
Thus, we need to calculate
$$4\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1+t^2}}{\frac{2}{(1+t^2)^2}-\frac{1}{1+t^2}+1}dt$$ or
$$4\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac{1+t^2}{t^4+1}dt$$  or
$$4\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+2}dt$$ or
$$4\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+2}dx,$$
which is $4\cdot\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}=2\sqrt2\pi$.

Comment: I've tried something like this for quite some time, would you happen to have a full solution?

Comment: @JayJuly I added something. See now.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Nice solution (without complex numbers) +1

Comment: We seem to have a conflict as to the coefficient,but I don't feel like checking my computation right now…

Comment: @Bernard I checked my solution again. I think all correct. I am ready to explain.

Comment: Don't you have a discontinuity for the change of variable in your interval of integration?  That's why I reduced it to $0$--$\pi/4.$. Added: There's another answer with the same answer as you, so it's probably me who did some mistake.

Comment: @Bernard It's $0-\frac{\pi}{2}$. We have four equal areas.By the way,  your solution is the same.

Comment: Why? There's a symmetry w.r.t. $x=\pi/4$ $\;(f(\pi/2-x)=f(x))$, so we have 8 equal areas. Or am I too tired?.

Comment: @Bernard Also $f(x)=f\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. I think it's a same idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64965/discussion-between-bernard-and-michael-rozenberg).

Comment: @JayJuly You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the other answers here, but I think the logic of it is more straightforward. It proceeds in three steps.

1. Reduce the integral using the half-angle formulae and periodicity considerations. This gives
   $$
   \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{\sin( x)^4 + \cos( x)^4} = 2\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1+\cos(2x)^2} = 8\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\cos(2x)^2}.
   $$
2. Convert the integrand to a rational function using an inverse trig substitution. In this case, $2x = \mathrm{cot}^{-1}(t)$ is the preferred option, as its derivative has no square roots and simple trigonometry gives $\cos[\cot^{-1}(t)] = t^2/(1+t^2)$. With this substitution, $dx = -dt/[2(1+t^2)]$ and
   $$
   8\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\cos(2x)^2} = 8\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{1}{1+t^2/(1+t^2)}\left[-\frac{dt}{2(1+t^2)}\right] = 4\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dt}{1+2t^2}.
   $$
3. Use rational function methods to evaluate the integral. I'm going to gloss over this one, though, as the integrand is clearly the derivative of an arctangent function. So we have
   $$
   4\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dt}{1+2t^2} = \left.\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}t\right)\right|_{-\infty}^\infty = 2\sqrt{2}\pi.
   $$

Thus, 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{\sin( x)^4 + \cos( x)^4} = 2\sqrt{2}\pi
$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

$$\sin^4x + \cos^4x = (\sin^2x + \cos^2x)^2 - 2\sin^2x\cos^2x = 1 - 2\sin^2x\cos^2x$$

And again

$$2\sin^2x\cos^2x = 2(\sin x \cos x)^2 = 2\left(\frac{\sin2x}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\sin^22x$$

Hence in the end

$$\sin^4x + \cos^4x = 1 - \frac{1}{2}\sin^22x$$

You can treat this.